# Type error in nltk freqdist using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk, frequency-distribution

I'm trying to get the most frequent words from a column (text strings) in my data by using nltk's FreqDist, after tokenizing the sentences.

However, after applying pandas dataframe, I get a column of lists instead of strings. So when running I get the error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

```py
df['Tokenized'] = df['Description'].map(tokenize)
word_dist = nltk.FreqDist(df['Tokenized']) #type error: unhashable type
```

Right now my Tokenized is a list. How do I resolve this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you share a sample of what `df` and `tokenize`?

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

`nltk.FreqDist` takes a list of strings as input. You fed in a pandas Series.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> from nltk import FreqDist

>>> df = pd.read_csv('x')
>>> df['Description']
0            Here is a sentence.
1    This is a foo bar sentence.
Name: Description, dtype: object

>>> df['Description'].map(word_tokenize)
0              [Here, is, a, sentence, .]
1    [This, is, a, foo, bar, sentence, .]
Name: Description, dtype: object

>>> sum(df['Description'].map(word_tokenize), [])
['Here', 'is', 'a', 'sentence', '.', 'This', 'is', 'a', 'foo', 'bar', 'sentence', '.']

>>> FreqDist(sum(df['Description'].map(word_tokenize), []))
FreqDist({'a': 2, 'sentence': 2, '.': 2, 'is': 2, 'This': 1, 'foo': 1, 'bar': 1, 'Here': 1})


>>> type(df['Description'].map(word_tokenize))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>


>>> type(sum(df['Description'].map(word_tokenize), []))
<class 'list'>
```